# Unable to get output in the object of array form

Tags: javascript, json

This the javascript array of objects

```
let input =[{
"name":"Star Plus","category":"Entertainment"
},{
"name":"Star News","category":"News"
},{
"name":"Times Now","category":"News"
}]
```

I want to get the output in this form

```
{
"News":["Star News","Times Now"],
"Entertainment":["Star Plus"]
}
```

I've tried with this code but it is not showing any output

```
Entertainment=[]
News=[]
for x in input:
    for(i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    if((x[i].category)=="Entertainment")
        Entertainment.push(x['name'])
    elseif((x[i].category)=="News")
        News.push(x['name'])
    else return false
document.write(News)
document.write(Entertainment)
```

Although my code is not showing any output but i think its hardcoding. Is there any better way to code this

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce()` method to get the result.

```js
let input = [
  {
    name: 'Star Plus',
    category: 'Entertainment',
  },
  {
    name: 'Star News',
    category: 'News',
  },
  {
    name: 'Times Now',
    category: 'News',
  },
];
const ret = input.reduce((prev, { category, name }) => {
  const p = prev,
    key = category;
  p[key] = p[key] ?? [];
  p[key].push(name);
  return p;
}, {});
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of groups in an object:

```js
const groups = {};
for (const {name, category} of input) {
    if (!(category in groups)) {
        groups[category] = [];
    }
    groups[category].push(name);
}
console.log(groups);
```